# Selenium: How to find text on page containing html tags? (Text Node)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**I updated the question after it was answered!**

I try to find a text in a list on the webpage, which contains a html tag like `<p> text </p>`.

Heres a screenshot how it does look like on the webpage:
[Screenshot of text to search for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oG8m.png)

Inside the "inspect" i used `//*[text()='<p> First do this, then this</p>']` which could be found as seen above in the screenshot.

In the code im using this codeline to find the text:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='<p> First do this, then this</p>']"))
```

But during the test run it gives this error message:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='
> First do this, then this']"}

As you can see, selenium does somehow ignore the html tags `<p> </p>`

**Answer and solution from cruisepandey:**

Thanks to @cruisepandey i know now, my text is inside a textnode.
The only way to get the text out is using this code:

```
var ele = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));
        Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
```

The output of this here is:
`<p> First do this, then this</p>`

Comment: Can you tag your binding  language as well, looks like it is C# . Also, can we have more outerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a text node, you cannot simply use `text()` method from xpath v1.0

You can try with below xpath :

```
(//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr)[1]/td[2]
```

**Code:**

```
var ele = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()"));
Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
```

**Code (With explicit waits) :** in you want to click on it.

```
var ele = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("(//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr)[1]/td[2]")));
Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
```

Comment: no, `//*` means select the current node, so if the text is unique, it should work. Also is it C# ?

Comment: First:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='First do this, then this']"}`
Second:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[text()='First do this, then this']"}`
Third:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(),'First do this, then this')]"}`

Comment: Can you tell me your binding language ?

Comment: The tags `<p>` are a part of the text. Check out the screenshot. Youll see in the list on the left, that those tags are displayed there. Also in the inspect on the right side, you see that they are displayed there.

Comment: It is C# yes. 
We use a template from GitHub which is called "RazorHero - Clean Architecture"
https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture

Comment: yes, that's look like a UI bug to me. Never show any tag `<>` in UI. It could lead to potential security breach, so you can raise that defect and get it fixed, meanwhile I need to know in which programming language you are working ?

Comment: Can you share Page resource as well  ? I have create an HTML at my end and can give you more constrictive solution

Comment: Check out also the inspect picture in my question. Youll see that i typed in the searchfield `"//*[text()='<p> First do this, then this</p>']"` which was found inside inspect. If i try to look for it, without the tags, it wont find the text

Comment: I got the issue, that's not a normal text, it's a text node. wait I am working on this

Comment: No, I need to know more outer HTML, can you print the page resource and share it with us here. You simply cannot locate using `//*[contains(text(), '<p> First do this, then this</p>')]`, cause I said, it's not normal text, it is a node (a text type)

Comment: We want to use Tags inside the list for the description. It is on purpose. Ill upload another screenshot in my question.

Comment: Could you tell me, how i can share the outer html? I can share it, just would like to know what part you exactly want.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML

Comment: i added it in the question on the very bottom. I clicked right click on it and then "Copy outer html"

Comment: That's just a single td, I won't be able to differentiate with other tds, can you share the entire page resource ? You can simply paste everything in a text file and upload it somewhere so that I can download that text file and make a replica of your web page in my local system

Comment: sure will do it. One second

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/YByRQrd1 i hope this helps =) I copied the html starting from "body"

Comment: Sure, will have a look

Comment: @Beardy : Updated my post above, please check it and let me know if that works.

Comment: where do i add the text "First do this, then this"? Because im looking explizit for the text only

Comment: You cannot, you can locate that element using the above xpath. What exactly you wanna do with that text ?

Comment: After i create these texts, they are being added to a list which you see after pressing on save. And there i want to check, if this texts i created can be found in the list.

Comment: Why not simply `.GetText()` ? on the above web element ? like this `ele.GetText()` print that using a console.writeLine and see if you are getting the right value or not  ? Moreover this technique makes more sense cause we are not hardcoding any text, so it's totally independent. you will always have a unstable code with hardcoded text in xpath, cause if that is not being display on screen you would see `NoSuchElement Exception`

Comment: Tried to use "GetText()" but it doesnt suggest this part in there. I get everything else like GetAttribute or GetType or GetProperty

Comment: You can use `.GetAttribute('innerHTML')`, should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So i used now this here: `var ele = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()")); ele.GetAttribute("innerHTML");`

Error Message:
`OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`

Comment: hey cruise, i was able to fix the error message above. According to another post i had to delete the `text()` and now it gets the attribute. But what i get is this here `Element (id = e7e87416-1e8d-40e0-a50a-93a7661728b8)` Any chance you could still help me to get out the text inside the list with getattribute?

Comment: can you share the code from which you are getting the desired text and that element id ?

Comment: sure here `var ele = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='mud-table-root']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));
            ele.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            Console.WriteLine(ele);` i used also yours before with the wait timer. I do also get the same id as with my code

Comment: what is the output of `Console.WriteLine(ele);` ?

Comment: The output is just `Element (id = 8e0bf73c-d96b-4d09-a3ef-01881f24ad68)`

Comment: No you should print `Console.WriteLine(ele.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));`

Comment: Oh wow, yeah thanks. But im getting this now:
`<!--!-->&lt;p&gt; First do this, then this&lt;/p&gt;` as output. Im worrying slowly that i wont be able to get the text out of the textnode tho

Comment: Can you try to print this as well `Console.WriteLine(ele.GetText());`

Comment: There is a red underline in the code which says "IWebElement does not contain a definition or method called getText()"

Comment: my bad, it should be this instead : `Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);`

Comment: It works!!! Thanks so much! Can you edit your answer so i can mark it as anwered?

Comment: Sure did mark it as answer. Maybe you could also edit your answer on the top so people dont need to scroll through all our comments :)

Comment: I have edited the post as well, if you think it needs more modification, you can edit it, I will approve from my end

Comment: @cruisepandey I sent you an email with the content that Mr.Prophet helped me, I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is the element tag name, not part of it's text.
Also possibly there are spaces in the text. In this case I prefer using `contains` instead of exactly equation text check.
Try this instead:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[contains(text(),'First do this, then this')]"))
```

Comment: Getting this error message: `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(),'First do this, then this')]"}`

Comment: Try adding a wait / delay before this line to let the page fully loaded. Also possibly that the element inside iframe.

Comment: In our case `p` is a part of the text.
Our application has a create button. After pressing on it, there is a ql-editor in which i type some text. After pressing on the save button, this text is going to be formatted and gets "html" tags. Those are needed, as our customers are getting messages per SMS on their phones. Those html tags, are helping to display messages correctly on the phone of the customers. In the screenshot above, you can see, that the tags are a part of the text

Comment: I have already a wait for 5 seconds before it looks for the text. This was also my first guess, that it goes too fast, but even after that wait, it wont find the text

Comment: Even if `<p>` is part of the text this should catch since I'm searching for text "contains"